# Trying to call a range of instances from a class using for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter

Firstly, sorry this is such a big code dump. I just wanted to make sure all the information was present.

So basically the whole goal is to make a working version of battleship. I will achieve this by making a large grid of buttons for both the players play area (where their ships are placed). Currently I am simply trying to set up some way of disabling one grid during one player's turn (so they can't attack their own ships) and the other for the other player. However, I am struggling to call the buttons by their name using the loop function I have below (named `enableAndDisableFunc`)

This is all simply just set up for the UI

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

base = Tk()

# **********************************
# UI SETUP *************************
# **********************************

# Base ****************************

baseTitle = Frame(base)
baseTitle.config(background="orange", height=20)
baseTitle.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

baseTop = Frame(base)
baseTop.config(background="blue")
baseTop.pack(side=TOP, fill="both")

baseBottom = Frame(base)
baseBottom.config(background="black", height=40)
baseBottom.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill="both")

# root ********************************

rootPL1 = Frame(baseTop)
rootPL1.config(background="red")
rootPL1.pack(side=LEFT)

emptySpace = Frame(baseTop)
emptySpace.config(background="grey", width=30)
emptySpace.pack(side=LEFT)

rootPL2 = Frame(baseTop)
rootPL2.config(background="red")
rootPL2.pack(side=LEFT)

# Sect(ion) *******************************************

SectPL1 = Frame(rootPL1)
SectPL1.config(background="green", height=30)
SectPL1.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

SectGridPL1 = Frame(rootPL1)
SectGridPL1.config(background="blue", height=400, width=150)
SectGridPL1.pack(side=BOTTOM)

SectPL2 = Frame(rootPL2)
SectPL2.config(background="green", height=30)
SectPL2.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

SectGridPL2 = Frame(rootPL2)
SectGridPL2.config(background="blue", height=400, width=150)
SectGridPL2.pack(side=BOTTOM)

# Pl(ayer) ***********************************

PL1ButGrid = Frame(SectGridPL1)
PL1ButGrid.grid(row=8, column=8)

PL1ShipHitCountTagLabel = Label(SectPL1, text="Ship Hit Count", anchor=E, padx=3)
PL1ShipHitCountTagLabel.pack(side=LEFT)

PL1ShipHitCount = 0
PL1ShipHitCountLabel = Label(SectPL1, text=str(PL1ShipHitCount), anchor=E, padx=3)
PL1ShipHitCountLabel.pack(side=LEFT)

# *********************************************

PL2ButGrid = Frame(SectGridPL2)
PL2ButGrid.grid(row=8, column=8)

PL2ShipHitCountTagLabel = Label(SectPL2, text="Ship Hit Count", anchor=E, padx=3)
PL2ShipHitCountTagLabel.pack(side=LEFT)

PL2ShipHitCount = 0
PL2ShipHitCountLabel = Label(SectPL2, text=str(PL2ShipHitCount), anchor=E, padx=3)
PL2ShipHitCountLabel.pack(side=LEFT)

# Switch Turn Button ********************************

SwitchButton = Button(baseBottom, width=20, height=2, text="Switch Turn to Other Player",
                      command=lambda: enableAndDisableFunc())
SwitchButton.pack(side=TOP)

# Title *********************************************
titleLabel = Label(baseTitle, text="Battleship!", font="Arial", fg="black", bg="orange", padx=10, pady=10)
titleLabel.pack(side=TOP)
```

This part loads the class that creates all the buttons that the player's grids are made from

```
# classes and methods
def colourChanger(self):
    self.button.config(bg="red")

    global PL2ShipHitCount
    global PL1ShipHitCount

    PL1ShipHitCount += 1
    PL2ShipHitCount += 1

    PL1ShipHitCountLabel.config(text=PL1ShipHitCount)
    PL2ShipHitCountLabel.config(text=PL2ShipHitCount)

    print("Working for cell " + str(self) + "!")
```

And finally this section is where each button's values are generated (using multiple loops to achieve all the details about each row, column, id and label)

```
grid1namelist = []
grid2namelist = []

class GameBoardButtons:

    def __init__(self, name, buttonText, buttonRow, buttonColumn, buttonState, frame):
        self.name = name
        self.button = Button(frame, text=buttonText, fg="grey", state=buttonState, command=lambda: colourChanger(self))
        self.button.grid(row=buttonRow, column=buttonColumn)

    def enable(self):
        self.button.config(state=NORMAL)

    def disable(self):
        self.button.config(state=DISABLED)

def buttonGen(givenFrame, iState):
    for i in range(1, 65):
        if 1 <= int(i) <= 8:
            iText = "A" + str(i)
            rowNum = 1
            colNum = i
        if 9 <= int(i) <= 16:
            iText = "B" + str((i % 8) + 1)
            rowNum = 2
            colNum = (i % 8) + 1
        if 17 <= int(i) <= 24:
            iText = "C" + str((i % 8) + 1)
            rowNum = 3
            colNum = (i % 8) + 1
        if 25 <= int(i) <= 32:
            iText = "D" + str((i % 8) + 1)
            rowNum = 4
            colNum = ((i % 8) + 1)
        if 33 <= int(i) <= 40:
            iText = "E" + str((i % 8) + 1)
            rowNum = 5
            colNum = ((i % 8) + 1)
        if 41 <= int(i) <= 48:
            iText = "F" + str((i % 8) + 1)
            rowNum = 6
            colNum = ((i % 8) + 1)
        if 49 <= int(i) <= 56:
            iText = "G" + str((i % 8) + 1)
            rowNum = 7
            colNum = ((i % 8) + 1)
        if 57 <= int(i) <= 64:
            iText = "H" + str((i % 8) + 1)
            rowNum = 8
            colNum = ((i % 8) + 1)
        if str(givenFrame) == ".!frame2.!frame.!frame2":
            iFrameValue = str(1)
            iName = "grid" + iFrameValue + "but" + iText
            grid1namelist.append(iName)
        else:
            iFrameValue = str(2)
            iName = "grid" + iFrameValue + "but" + iText
            grid2namelist.append(iName)

        iName = GameBoardButtons(iName, iText, rowNum, colNum, iState, givenFrame)
        print(iName)

# Main setup for grids
buttonGen(SectGridPL1, iState=NORMAL)
buttonGen(SectGridPL2, iState=DISABLED)

def enableAndDisableFunc():
    switchTurnPopUp(1)
    switchTurnPopUp(2)
    messagebox.showinfo("Turn Switcher", "It is now player " + str(2) + "'s turn")

def switchTurnPopUp(gridNum):
    if gridNum == 1:
        for i in grid1namelist:
            i.button.enable()
    if gridNum == 2:
        for i in grid2namelist:
            i.button.disable()

base.mainloop()
```

How do I disable (set the `state=DISABLED`) one whole set of buttons on one grid (all of grid 1 or, in other words, all the possibilities of **"grid1"** + **"A" to "H"** + **"1" to "8"**). This will allow the player only to choose a grid coord on their opponents grid using the tkinter disable function.

Many thanks, sorry for the large code dump and the messy ordering of code, all and any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is way too much code. Please condense it down to a [mcve]. We don't need all your code, we just need the smallest bit of code that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: Trying to call a range of instances

If you use `gridxnamelist` only for toogle purpose, its obsolet.

Change the following:

- Pass the Grid `Frame` to `switchTurnPopUp`

  ```
  def enableAndDisableFunc():
      switchTurnPopUp(SectGridPL1)
      switchTurnPopUp(SectGridPL2)
  ```
- Replace your `switchTurnPopUp` with this:

  ```
  def switchTurnPopUp(grid):
      # Unkown 'state' for this 'grid'
      state = None

      # Get all children 'id' from this 'grid'
      children = grid.children

      # Loop the children 'id'
      for c in children:

          # Get the 'widget' of this 'id'
          widget = children[c]

          # Process only 'Button' widgets
          if isinstance(widget, (Button)):

              # Check the 'state' only once
              if state is None:

                  # Get the current 'state' of the first 'Button'
                  state = widget.cget('state')

                  # Toogle the state
                  if state == 'normal':
                      state = 'disabled'
                  elif state == 'disabled':
                      state = 'normal'

              # Set the toogled 'state'
              widget.configure(state=state)
  ```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - TkVersion: 8.6***